# Передача значений переменных в Java

Tags: java, переменные, доступ

Написал класс синглтон. В нем есть поле:

```
private ArrayList<Cash> storageList;
```

И геттер:

```
public ArrayList getStorageList();
return this.storageList;
```

Когда я из другого класса вызываю следующий метод:

```
CashStorage.getCashStorage().getStorageList().set(1, new Cash());
```

Компилятор это нормально пропускает. Но ведь поле storageList приватное, почему тогда получив ссылку из другого класса я имею возможность на него воздействовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Но Вы же геттером на него "воздействуете", а геттер публичный.

Comment: геттером я получаю его, а set(1,new Cash()) воздействую, заменяя элемент с индексом 1 на новый. Получается, что объект storageList изменяется.

Comment: @Mr.Mazle ну так вы ж сами пишите "геттером я **получаю его**".....что не так? получили через метод....напрямую обратиться нельзя CashStorage.getCashStorage().storageList -.... все логично

Comment: Я получаю ссылку, по которой могу воздействовать на приватный объект другого класса. А определение приватного поля - "Могут изменяться только методами внутри данного класса". Я может что то не так понимаю. Объясните, может в моей логике что то не верно

Comment: @Mr.Mazle ну вот с этим вопросом можно смело обращаться к Егору Бугаенко. Он считает это прямым нарушением инкапсуляции и считает что геттеров и сеттеров не должно быть вообще))) А в целом геттером ты, по сути, отдаешь на растерзание поле во вне любому, кто его попросит.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что когда вы пишете геттер, вы вправе не давать прямую ссылку на объект, а создать новый и отдать его, например:

```
public ArrayList<Cash> getStorageList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(this.storageList);
}
```

Comment: Но я ведь правильно понял, что в случае создания публичного гетера для приватного поля, приватность поля становится бессмысленной? я имею ввиду, когда мы не присваиваем новую ссылку, а даем напрямую на объект поля?

Answer (score -1):

Ну если ты хочешь, чтобы он не изменялся используй final.
И насчет доступа к приватным полям, насколько мне известно, к ним можно получать доступ с помощью рефлексии (без геттеров и сеттеров).

Comment: Я хочу чтобы он изменялся только методами внутри класса, чтобы извне поменять данное поле стало невозможным (если исключить рефлексию). если поставим final -то я и внутри класса не смогу его изменить.

Comment: Ну в таком случае не создавай геттеры и сеттеры, ибо они доступ дают к приватным полям. Нет геттера и сеттера - нет доступа из вне. Просто сделай тогда приватные методы для изменения этого поля и сможешь менять только внутри.

Comment: final не поможет - мы не сможем менять само поле, т.е., присвоить ссылку на другой лист, например. Но менять ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ листа, который final никто не запрещает. ДУмаю, автору нужно почитать про клонирование и в геттере отдавать не сам лист, а его клон.